# Hide Azure Databricks logs

Tags: azure, logging, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am running code locally on my computer, which uses Azure Databricks cluster. Because of this I am getting a lot of "View job details at https://adb......" statements. I am logging other things, so I cannot turn off logging itself. How can I remove this information from being displayed?
[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot of the verbose

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: You'll need to add more details to your question, we do not know what command you're running or where you're running this locally